# Dell XPS 13 7390 from Dell will not boot to desktop

Tags: dell

I am using a Dell XPS 13 7390 with Ubuntu 18.04, purchased from Dell in December 2019.

It was working great until today when Firefox disappeared.  
After I closed Firefox I couldn't start it again. It just wasn't there (at least search in GUI and terminal couldn't find it). So I went for lunch and when I got back it wouldn't let me sign in (password wasn't accepting any characters), so I pushed power button to turn it off.

Turned it on and it boots to command prompt instead of GUI.
I run

```
sudo systemcd set-default grpahical.target
```

It loads the desktop background and that is all.
Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04   from Dell.  I just run updates whenever I got prompted to do it.

Comment: This looks like a damage to the file system. A hardware issue (or just a one-time hardware hickup) may be at the origin. You probably will need to reinstall because there is no guarantee about the integrity of the remaining files. However, at this stage I recommend you to have your system serviced while it is still under warranty.