# 18.04 Can't connect to some company internal sites with VPN

Tags: 18.04, dell, vpn, xps, vpnc

Dell XPS13-7390 with Ubuntu 18.04, purchased from Dell in December 2019.

I've restored it to the factory settings because of  [[Dell XPS 13 7390 from Dell will not boot to desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210624/dell-xps-13-7390-from-dell-will-not-boot-to-desktop][1])

I connect to  company VPN (VPNC) and then I run into following problem:

- some sites  I can access (Jira, Confluence, other internal sites)
- I cannot access some other internal sites (I can access them on Windows box)
- I can access stash; For example I can clone via https, but not via ssh
- I don't know what to do next, any help is appreciated

VPN connected

`````
-XPS-13-7390:~/work$ route 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     50     0        0 tun0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
4.16.198.74     _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp2s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     50     0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlp2s0````

VPN disconnected 
-XPS-13-7390:~/work$ route 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0````
`````

Comment: 1) Which browser are you using? 2) Is it updated to its latest version? 3) Try using a different browser for testing purposes. 4) Does this occur when at work and not using VPN? 5) What does your company IT team say? 6) https://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/ may be helpful.  -  When responding, please use [edit] to put the facts into your question so all the info's in one place. Please do not respond with Add Comment as that has almost no formatting ability.

Comment: Tried both Firefox and Chrome latest versions, it makes no difference.  At the office it is still the same issue (we need to connect to the VPN regardless if we are working from home or in the office).   IT department is still looking at it, but so far they couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. In VPN connection I had to modify the settings for IPv4 and IPv6.  I had to change them both from "Automatic" to "Disabled".